# Google Chrome failing to fetch pages from one specific site on one specific Ubuntu user account

Tags: google-chrome

I use the latest version of Chrome:

- Version 106.0.5249.119 (Official Build) (64-bit))

on an up-to-date Ubuntu 20.4:

- Linux ray-desktop 5.15.0-46-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 19:15:44 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

For a while (perhaps a few months), I've been getting this message:

> This site can’t be reached
> The web page at
> https://www.etymonline.com might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
> ERR_FAILED

So today I tried the same thing on Firefox and it worked fine.

I logged in as a different user, and in Chrome it worked fine.

I turned off developer mode and all extensions, restarted Chrome, and it still fails.
The Chrome console shows:

```
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.                   VM264:6792
    (anonymous) @   VM87:6792
The FetchEvent for "https://www.etymonline.com/" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected.
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous)         @ sw.js:39
```

This happens only for the etymonline.com site, only in Chrome, and only in the one Linux account.

Any idea where I can go from here in determining the cause of the problem?

Comment: try clearing cookies/using incognito mode?

Comment: You may have to remove Chrome profile (config) information from that user. But, first try the above suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's only one user and only one site, it's possible that some cookie has been corrupted or otherwise is causing the issue. You can test this by using Incognito Mode: if the site works properly in Incognito Mode, the issue is most likely being caused by a cookie. Clearing the cookies that the site uses should solve the problem.

Comment: Incognito didn't have the problem, so I cleared the cookies for that site, and the problem is gone. Thanks.